# Why am I not able to see the random numbers generated using python for large input values?

Tags: python, random, adjacency-matrix

So I am trying to generate my own adjacency list using random.randint. I am not able to view the output.

Its just few values and then dots. I want to input these values into my algorithm. How to view these generated values.

[This is the output I'am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wvXb.png)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: That's a numpy array `str` representation. Convert it to a `list` (by reading numpy's documentation) and then print it.

Comment: You literally need to see them?  The values are there in the array and you can get them usually normal array operations.  If you really want to *see* the entire array, use `numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=10000)`

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: you could run `np.sum(a)` to make sure that you have all 250k values there.  the expected mean is 125k, but the full 95% CI is [124510, 125490]

Answer (score 0):

The below code should help:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.random.randint(0,2, size=(500,500))
print(a)

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df)
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```